# ARM template automation

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-rm-template

I am working with VS to build out ARM templates as well as the associated DSC scripts needed. I have everything working but noticed that anytime I make a change to my DSC script, I need to manually copy it over to my DSC resources folder before deploying.

With that in mind, is there a way within VS to automatically copy over the .ps1 into the needed directory before deploying?

Thanks,

Comment: work on it right in that directory?

Comment: @4c74356b41 That was my first thought but the directory is actually a .zip file. Since I cant open and edit the files within the .zip from VS, that will not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with VS, but I have a workflow to work with DSC, basically I have a directory with DSC zip files and directory with dsc configuration files and when I'm ready to deploy i run a powershell script that among all other things updates DSC zip files and uplaods them.

```
Get-ChildItem "%path%" -File -Filter *.zip | ForEach-Object {
    Compress-Archive -Path "%path\$($_.BaseName).ps1" -DestinationPath $_.FullName -Update
    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Container 'packages' -File $_.FullName -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
}
```

This needs Powershell 5+, but you can add file to zip archive using windows native methods in any Powershell

Comment: Thats not a bad idea and one I will use. I assumed that there may be a way to automate adding items to the existing .zip using msbuild via VS but until then, this works for me.

Comment: btw, you can use `publish-azurermvmdscextension -archivepath` or something like that to create archives from scratch